# WP8 define multiple preprocessor values

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, c-preprocessor

I know that we can declare Preprocessor values in the properties settings of any app.

[image]

I can declare two or three macros in the Conditional compilation symbols, but what if I want to define 25 values here? Is there any other way, like a .cs file where I can link all my definitions here.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you having some problem inserting your 25 values here?

Comment: Yes, Is there a better option to view my defines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually edit the .csproj file using Visual Studio's text editor.

1. Right click on your project in *Solution Explorer*.
2. Select *Unload Project*
3. Right click on your (unloaded) project in *Solution Explorer*.
4. Select *Edit MyProject.csproj*
5. Find the `DefineConstants` elements and edit your defined symbols there directly. The settings for Debug and Release configurations are in separate `PropertyGroup` elements.
6. Right click on your (unloaded) project in *Solution Explorer*.
7. Select *Reload Project*

Comment: Can I define all of the values in a file and link the file here ?

Comment: You can import other MSBuild project files using the <Import> element, yes. You can just copy-paste the PropertyGroup elements and leave only the DefineConstants child element there. If you import this file after the PropertyGroups in the project file, your values from the imported file will overwrite those in the project file.

Comment: Thank you, can you give one example?

Comment: @Sander can you please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306471/how-to-use-prefix-pch-in-wp8-like-in-ios/21310614?noredirect=1#comment33512184_21310614

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't define them somewhere and use in the other files. [MSDN page about define says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx):

> The scope of a symbol that was created by using #define is the file in
>   which the symbol was defined.