# How to use Prefix.pch in WP8 like in iOS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8, prefix

In iOS I have 5 application which use same code. I was able to refer the common classes and separate the application name, theme and color using the values from the Prefix.pch file. My Prefix file has these,

```
#define APPLICATION_NAME @"Application01"
#define APPLICATION_THEME @"Brown"
```

By using these macros defined my prefix file, in my program I can say

```
#if APPPLICATION_THEME = @"Brown"
-perform this-
```

I would like to follow the same approach in WP8. I don't know where do I define these macro values and to use them in the code. Please help me in achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

`#define APPLICATION_NAME @"Application01"` by `#define APPLICATION_NAME_Application01`

and

`#if APPPLICATION_THEME = @"Brown"` by `#if APPPLICATION_THEME_Brown`

additional the instead of `#define` you can just set it in the project properties in the menu `Build->Conditional compilation Symbols:` and just put `APPLICATION_NAME_Application01`

Comment: is there any other way without adding it to Conditional compilation Symbols: ? as i have around 50+ macors and its difficult to add and remove in Conditional compilation Symbols

Comment: @user2056563 there is only two ways that I know how one is by explicitly writing in the code the #define ... and other is in the Conditional compilation Symbols so you can create like a master defines page where you set all the #defines.

Comment: Please have a look here you will understand what i am looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22094143/macros-in-prefix-pch-file-equivalent-in-wp8

Comment: master defines page ? how to do it ? can you please show me how ?

Comment: the reply to the question you posted is exactly what's in the reply in the first line

Answer (score 0):

C# language supports defines which can be defined either globally in the project file or you can define them on top of any file:

```
#define USE_BROWN_THEME
```

However, using application name is set in the `WMAppManifest.xml` file and you can only check/read it at runtime, you cannot do that at compile time. And xml files don't play well with `#define`s.

[#define (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x.aspx)